# MySQL unknown column in subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to implement a "rolling average" for a table `contests` with just two columns `id` and `ideas_count` (int) in MySQL:

For each row in `contests` return `id` and the average of `ideas_count` for the last 10 rows before and including the current.

This is where I am stuck:

```
select 
  id, (
    select avg(ideas_count) from (
      select * from contests c2 where c2.id<=c1.id order by id desc limit 10
    ) prev
  ) 
from 
  contests c1
order by 
  id asc;
```

MySQL returns the error: "`Unknown column 'c1.id' in 'where clause'`"

Why is that?

How can I make this work?

#### Update

```
select 
  id, (
    select avg(ideas_count) from contests c2 
    where c2.id <= c1.id order by id desc limit 10
  ) 
from 
  contests c1
order by 
  id asc;
```

will **not** work, because it calculates the `avg` **first** and applies the `limit` **after**, whereas I need the **average of the last 10 rows**.

#### Update 2

Added an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8286f1).

Comment: Refer [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subquery-restrictions.html)
Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries. They are materialized in whole (evaluated to produce a result set) before evaluating the outer query, so they cannot be evaluated per row of the outer query.

Comment: @Damodaran thanks for clearing up the "why" part! Any ideas for the "how else"?

Comment: Could you please provide sample data along with table structure in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a couple of sequence numbers, generated in sub queries. Then joining the sub queries based on those sequence numbers.

```
SELECT sub1.id, 
        AVG(sub2.ideas_count) AS rolling_average
FROM
(
    SELECT id, ideas_count, @seq1:=@seq1 + 1 AS seq
    FROM contests
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq1:=0) sub0
    ORDER BY id
) sub1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, ideas_count, @seq2:=@seq2 + 1 AS seq
    FROM contests
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq2:=0) sub0
    ORDER BY id
) sub2
ON sub2.seq BETWEEN sub1.seq -9 AND sub1.seq
GROUP BY sub1.id
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I actually still wonder why :-) Is this the simplest way to achieve the rolling average in MySQL?

Comment: Best I can think of! If there are NO gaps in the range of id fields then you could use the id rather than the sequence numbers from the sub queries, but in general it is VERY unlikely that there are no gaps on live data.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it can help

```
select id , avg(ideas_count)
from (
    select t1.id, t1.t_id, t1.ideas_count, @i:=if(@j < t1.id, 1, @i+1) as i, @j:=t1.id as j
    from ( select c1.id, c2.id as t_id, c2.ideas_count
           from contests c2 join contests c1 on c2.id<=c1.id 
           order by c1.id asc, c2.id desc
        ) as t1
        join (select @i:=0, @j:=0) as t2
    ) as t3
where i <=10
group by id
```

Comment: Looks good for the first result rows but then starts yielding wrong values.

Comment: @MoMolog I edited the answer, although the result is different to Kickstart's result, but I think mine is correct

Answer (score 0):

you can update your query to be:

```
select 
id, (select avg(ideas_count) from  
(select * from contests c2) prev where prev.id<=c1.id  order by prev.id desc limit 10 )     
as average 
from 
contests c1
order by id asc;
```

Comment: No, this will not work, unfortunately, because it calculates the `avg` **first** and applies the `limit` **after**, whereas I need the **average of the last 10 rows**. Try it out for yourself.

Comment: @MoMolog what about this

Comment: this cannot work because `prev` will always return the same 10 rows. Filtering them afterwards does not fix this.

Comment: Same problem. Try it out!